# datastax mahout cant create TFIDF vectors from datastax solr indexing

Tags: solr, lucene, mahout, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I run datastax 4.5 mahout on the solr indexing created by datastax 4.5.

```
dse mahout lucene.vector
--dir /var/lib/cassandra/data/solr.data/test.test/index/ 
--field body 
--dictOut $WORK_DIR/solr/wikipedia/dict.txt
--output $WORK_DIR/solr/wikipedia/out.txt 
--max 50
```

In the mahout [page](http://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html) mentions "Your Lucene index must be created with the same version of Lucene used in Mahout.
As of Mahout 0.9 this is Lucene 4.6.1. ". 
datastax 4.5 only offered mahout 0.8. I got Exception as it said in the page.

I installed Mahout 0.9 and tried the same command to read the datastax solr index.  I got error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'dse452' does not exist." It seems datastax have modified the solr index information.

Any clues about solving the compatible issue?

Answer (score 0):

Include the Lucene Codecs JAR on your classpath: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-codecs

Comment: Hi, I add this package to mahout classpath, it doesnt work. the same error. I dont know weather it supporsts 'dse452'

Comment: Is dse452 something that Mahout uses? Google doesn't turn up much http://goo.gl/hAEMJB

Comment: The index is created by solr integrated in datastax. 'dse' standards for 'datastax enterprise'. I assume '452' is the version number.

Comment: In that case DataStax uses their own custom codec (which determines how Lucene encodes and decodes data written to disk). You'll need to include the JAR from Datastax that contains this codec. Lucene dynamically loads only the codec classes it needs at runtime using an internal component called SPI (service provider interface). This looks in the file `META-INF/services` for a list of codecs. So if you have trouble finding the correct JAR file, look for the one with that file in it.

Comment: I meant to say `META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec` above. But it's using Solr so it's not there. I believe the JAR you need is `lib/dse-4.5.2.jar` and the codecs are in `./com/datastax/bdp/search/lucene/codecs/`. So add that JAR to the classpath and try creating a `META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec` file in your project's classpath. The file should just contain "com.datastax.bdp.search.lucene.codecs.DseCodec". See this tutorial if you have trouble understanding how Lucene loads codecs: http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/06/05/build-your-own-lucene-codec/